Whenever i start a transparent activity from background, it opens on top of the already existing app
Whenever i start a transparent activity from broadcast reciever, if the app already has an activity in that is in the recent apps, instead of being transparent, over the current app, its transparent over the already existing activity of the already existing app
Heres my what i use to open a new activity
val mIntent =  Intent(context, TakePicture::class.java)
mIntent.flags = (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
context.startActivity(mIntent)



Please explain what "open from background" means. Please explain what is the "already existing app" versus what is "the current app". https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

is it better now? @dominicoder

@Ryfter you mean you need to clear the activity stack?

@AmruthaSaj thx, its what i was looking for, you can answer and i'll accept it

I needed to add the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK flag on the intent
val mIntent = Intent(context, TakePicture::class.java)
mIntent.flags = (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK )
context.startActivity(mIntent)

